# Distorted sound quality via Bose QC35 headphones on Juno

Tags: release-juno, sound, bluetooth

I tried connecting my Bose QC35 Bluetooth headphones to my Dell XPS 13, on a new installation of elementaryOS Juno. I hear a hissing noise in the headphones, which does not change in its volume. When I start playing music, it is very distorted and poor in quality.

I've used Ubuntu before, so anytime I encounter this, I know that I would have to go to Sound settings and switch to using the "High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)" mode.

But when I went to my sound settings in eOS, all I see is this:

[image]

I don't see a setting to change that. Next, after some googling, I learnt that I could setup PulseAudio Volume Control and switch it in there in the  "Configuration" tab. But when I do that, nothing seems to happen! I still encounter poor audio quality.

How do I get this to work? Are there any other solutions to this that I am missing?

Comment: Let's see what profile is used: connect your bluetooth headset and play some audio to make sure they work (even if poorly). In Terminal run   `pacmd stat`   and then edit your question to include the output.

Answer (score 0):

Had some similar problem with a full bluetooth headphone.. Installed PulseEffects, did some Tweaks and it worked fine.. later on the problem came back but I think you could try that.